# How do I store an encryption/decryption key in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, encryption

Let's say I have a program written in VB.Net with encryption code that relies on a key being set to encrypt and decrypt. How do I securely store the key in the program? If it's plain text in the code, it could be reverse engineered. If it's a setting, then it is stored as plain text in the `x.exe.config` file and even easier to find.

Can the `x.exe.config` file be set to encypt? If not, what's the safest way of hard coding the key into the program?

The method I've used is encrypted using a different method, then encode that (as it's non-ascii text) and store that in the settings, but that in turn could be decoded if the program is reverse engineered.

What do other people do in this situation?

Comment: It depends on what you are encrypting and how you are doing it. Windows has an encryption key storage system and there are APIs for using it.  Whether it would be useful depends on the context and usage.

Comment: It also matters how portable you need the data to be. Could this data ever need to be decrypted by a different computer? What if you have a system failure and need to move the whole program to a different machine (that may use a different machine key)?

Comment: As always, who do you want to protect this key from? What's your threat model?

Comment: The purpose of this bit is to store a password that the clients use to access the database. The password is encrypted and stored as a file in a shared directory. This works fine, but my concern is the security of the key used to create the encrypted data. The key will be the same on all clients so that they can all decrypt the stored file and accces the database. If the key is in settings as plain text, it's obvious what it is. If it's plain text in the code, it _could_ be reverse engineered.

Comment: Even using something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397867(v=vs.110).aspx could be an issue. As it's the clients that are decrypting, they will need the full key. As you can tell, I'm rather new to this...

Answer (score 0):

You've set to an impossible task. The problem is that by hardcoding the key into the program, as you've noted, the user can still get the key by reverse engineering. If you put it in a file somewhere, the program needs to be able to read it, and therefore the user can also access it in the same way.

The fundamental problem you have is that the software needs to access the key, and for that, the key must be stored somewhere it's reachable by the user too. It can be within the binary or in the computer, but the binary can be analyzed and the file system can be inspected. Encrypting a file protects the key, but just recreates the problem with the new key.

This is also the very same problem that all DRM schemes face. They give users access to the the full software but want to limit it in some ways, but the user has everything in his computer to run the software. That's why it's always possible to pirate every desktop software, if enough effort is put towards it. You only can make it more difficult by obfuscating the key.

### But what can you do then?

An alternative approach is to not have the user to have the DB credentials at all. Or make them useless for anything significant. I can think of two approaches here:

- Have the system communicate with a webservice and never to the DB directly. This way, the user only knows the address of the server and the WS can request any authentication as needed, before going to the DB. The WS is then the only one to ever touch the DB. This is what all websites do in practice, the visitor doesn't ever sees the DB, but interacts with it though the web server.
- Another option would be to give the user direct DB access, but those credentials only give permission to call some stored procedures (or access views without sensitive data) and those in turn request some sort of authentication before proceeding. This way the DB credential becomes not that sensitive as long as its permissions are kept to the bare minimum and privileged actions are properly validated before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Alejandro. Couple of issues with the proposals. 1) this requires an  internet connection which isn't always possible for a client PC due to corporate policies. 2) Dynamic SQL prevents the storage of procedures. The SQL Server access isn't an issue as the client program uses SQL Server authenticity, so the user can't have direct access. What I was looking for was a "secure" way of encrypting the password for this "SQL Server authenticity" user so all clients could access it.

Comment: @Tym 1) Nothing of what I've said requires internet connection, everything is within the local network, for example if your current DB server is in the LAN. There is no need to go to internet for accesing the LAN. 2) I don't know what you're refering to here, but having code in stored procedures don't precludes at all the usage of dynamic SQL. Both options are feasible in your current setting, as long as you do proper changes in architecture. But as for securely encrypting DB credentials, it's impossible. If the software can decrypt them, any user (potentially malicious) also can.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood. However, if I'm using an intranet webservice, surely the client needs to log on to that too, so we're back to square 1...

Comment: @Tym Most likely yes, some sort of authentication is needed, but you still have a great advantage. You can request the **application** user/password instead of the DB one, just like all websites do (when you login into stackoverflow for example, you enter those credentials, but we have no idea of the underlying DB). The client sends those instead, which the user must know, but he never sees the DB, eliminating the need for saving the password. You just need to configure the address in the client, which is public information anyway.